# Why do my JqueryMobile radio buttons lose style when closing SimpleDialog2 on same page div?

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have a jQueryMobile app and Im running into a problem whereby my radio buttons appear to deselect when I close a SimpleDialog2 dialog. This only happens when the dialog opens on the same 'page' as the radio buttons.

Basically I have 3 sets of radio buttons on my page - (here is one set)

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">   
 <div data-role="content">
   <input type="radio" name="radio_set_1" id="one" value="one" checked="checked" />
   <label for="one">One</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio_set_1" id="two" value="two"/>
   <label for="two">Two</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

I open a dialog (SimpleDialog2) on the same page -

```js
$('#page1').simpledialog2({ 
    mode: 'button',
    headerText: "Dialog Title",
    headerClose: true,  
    buttonPrompt:"Prompt text",
    buttons: {
        'OK': {
            click:function() {
            }
        }
    }
  });
```

When this dialog gets closed the radio buttons appear to become deselected (both buttons lose their checked style). I can tell that actually the radio button is checked in my code it just loses its checked style. I have tried applying the refresh method -

```js
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

But this hasnt worked.

When I open a simpleDialog2 dialog on a different 'page' div and then close this dialog and return to page1 the radio buttons keep their style correctly.

Any ideas?